# Allocating songs to both sides of a CD

Tags: integer-programming, operations-research, constraints

> **1)** There are $8$ songs on a $2$-sided CD, of the following durations: $8$, $3$, $5$, $5$, $9$, $6$, $7$ and $12$ minutes. Each
>   side has a capacity of $30$ minutes. However, we want to distribute
>   the songs so that each side is about the same number of minutes. Formulate this problem
>   as an integer programming problem. Clearly define your variables,
>   objective and constraints.

I'm thinking about

```
MIN( S(X) - T(X))
```

where     S(X) = side 1 and T(X) = side 2? but don't know how to formulate this with the constraints?

> **2)** Formulate the following

```
  MAX            2x - 79y
  Subject To     0 ≤ x ≤ 20 and 0 ≤ y ≤ 30
```

and at least one of the following inequalities holds:

```
−2x1 + 3x2 ≥ 0
 5x1 − 4x2 ≥ 0
 7x1 + 8x2 ≤ 40.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** this is an instance of the *optimization* version of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). Choose $8$ binary decision variables $x_i \in \{\pm 1\}$ such that

$$8 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 5 x_3 + 5 x_4 + 9 x_5 + 6 x_6 + 7 x_7 + 12 x_8$$

is as close to zero as possible. You may want to use the function $y \mapsto 2 y - 1$ so that the decision variables take values in $\{0,1\}$. Since you have to use IP, choosing the objective function is tricky.

Comment: But surely that will mean an even number of tracks will be on each cd rather than even time @Rodrigo de Azevedo

Comment: @SamHarper Do you want both sides to have the same number of minutes or the same number of songs?

Comment: same number of minutes

Comment: @SamHarper Choose $x_1 = x_7 = x_8 = 1$ and $x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = -1$.

Comment: You are NOT required to solve this integer programming problem. Just need to define your variables, objective and constraints

Comment: You are NOT required to solve this integer programming problem. Just need to define your variables, objective and constraints

Comment: Could you check my solution and see if this is something that you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I have formulated one for you and I have solved it using excel solver.  Not the data that you provided but for a sum of all minutes which are divisible by 2 and the tricky objective function that the other responder was alluding.  Goodluck.

[image]

[image]

[image]